# Custom email notification on build completion in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, build-definition, custom-notification

**Background -**

I have multiple jobs running under my Azure DevOps project. I have set the custom email notification on the build completion to send emails to specific users.

**Issue -**

This notification works properly for all the build pipelines which are created under this project. But I want to set the notification for some of the jobs/definitions only which starts with the some word.
I can see the filter field `Definition name` and operator `contains` but I'm not able to find it's description on Microsoft documentation regarding it's usage.

So what's the way to get build completion notifications for few jobs in which definition name contains specific word or starts with some name ?

Answer (score 1):

> the way to get build completion notifications for few jobs in which definition name contains specific word or starts with some name

Based on your requirement, you indeed can use the `Definition name` field and `contains` operator to achieve it.

Here is an example:

[image]

The value field can be set to a word/string/part of a word.

For example:

Definition name contains tes -> the build definition name contains word tes(e.g. test, test-xx and so on) will send notification after build completing.

I checked the official documentation and it seems that there is currently no detailed description of this field.

Comment: I tried the same, but if the name contains xyztest, then also it's sends the notification. I want that it should only send the notification for the name which starts with 'tes'.

Comment: I can get your point now. I am afraid that the filter is not able to achieve this for the time being. It will only check if it contains word and cannot locate if it is at the beginning